# Spring webflow string converter which is password field aware

Tags: spring, passwords, type-conversion, trim, spring-webflow-2

I have created a custom string converter for spring webflow that trims spaces for every String property

```
public class StringTrimmerConverter implements Converter {

    public Object convertSourceToTargetClass(final Object object, final Class clazz) throws Exception {
        if ((object != null) && (object.getClass() == getSourceClass()) && (clazz == getTargetClass())) {
            return ((String) object).trim();
        }
        return object;
    }

    public Class<String> getSourceClass() { return String.class; }

    public Class<String> getTargetClass() { return String.class; }
}
```

It is added in conversion services

```
public class FlowConversationService extends DefaultConversionService {

    protected void addDefaultConverters() {
        super.addDefaultConverters();
        this.addConverter(new StringTrimmerConverter());
    }
}
```

Is there a way to disable this converter for password fields only?

I'm using spring webflow 2.3.2.RELEASE and spring 3.2.2.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force a specific converter with [`<binding>` configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#view-binder).

Alternatively you can store password field in `char[]`. I had discussions with people which prefer this over `String` as char array will not get interned.

Comment: Thanks, char[] solution works perfectly for me. *[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords)* are more reasons why you should prefer char[] to String for password fields.

Comment: That is what *"char will not get interned"* meant ;).